# Getting data from sharedPreference to a specific activity

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Is it possible to get a sharedprefence data from MainActivity_A and fetch it only to MainActivity_B and the other activities like MainActivity_C and MainActivity_D cannot access the data that has been fetched to MainActivity_B?

Comment: Shared preferences are available globally in your app, but you only need to fetch the data you care about in a given activity, so it's unclear what you are really asking here... Data in shared preferences is not "fetched to a specific activity"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well It totally depends on you wheather you wanna get that data or not..once you store data in shared preference with key then just get that data in the specific activity you want Thats It !!

For Example in Activity X you save the Shared Preference value like this

```
public static final String SHARED_PREFS = "sharedPrefs";

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS,MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putString("Key",Value);
```

Then in Activity A you want to use this value then you can do it like this

```
SharedPreferences pref;

pref = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String Value = pref.getString("Key");
```

In This way the value will be stored in variable String
And if you don't want the value in other activity then just don't call it !!